# New line with invisible character

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm sure this has been answered before but after attempting to search for others who had the problem I didn't have much luck.

I am using csv.reader to parse a CSV file. The file is in the correct format, but on one of the lines of the CSV file I get the notification "list index out of range" indicating that the formatting is wrong. When I look at the line, I don't see anything wrong. However, when I go back to the website where I got the text, I see a square/rectangle symbol where there is a space. This symbol must be leading csv.reader to treat that as a new line symbol.

A few questions: 1) What is this symbol and why can't I see it in my text files? 2) How do I avoid having these treated as new lines? I wonder if the best way is to find and replace them given that I will be processing the file multiple times in different ways.

Here is the symbol:

[image: character causing new line]

Update: When I copy and paste the symbol into Google it searches for Â (a-circumflex). However, when I copy and paste Â into my documents, it shows up correctly. That leads me to believe that the symbol is not actually Â.

Comment: What is *what* symbol?  Please provide an example.  Cut-n-paste the text from the website if possible or provide a link.

Comment: Might be a carriage return (`\r`)?

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a charset problem. The "Â" is latin-1 for [a non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) in UTF-8. Assuming you are running Windows, you are using one of the latins as character set. UTF-8 is the default encoding for OSX and Linux-based OSs. The OS locale is used as default locale in most text editors, and thus encode files created with those programs as latin-1. A lot of programmers on OSX have problems with non-breaking spaces because it is very easy to mistakenly type it (it is Option+Spacebar) and impossible to see.

In python >= 3.1, the csv reader supports dialects for solving those kind of problems. If you know what program was used to create the csv file, you can manually specify a dialect, like 'excel'. You can use a [csv sniffer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer) to automatically deduce it by peeking into the file.

**Life Management Advice**: If you happen to see weird characters *anywhere*, always assume charset problems. There is an awesome charset problem debug table [HERE](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html).

Comment: Yes, you're right. More details: Looking more carefully at the source code of the webpage I found this character: \u0085. This is apparently unicode for signalling "next line" (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0085/index.htm).